# When will MS Graph API be out of Beta?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Microsoft Graph API is still providing the Beta vs. v1.0 APIs.
There are many things not available for the 1.0, only in Beta.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/

My question: is there any news/plans/knowledge of when might Microsoft be enabling the Beta as next official release version?

If I implement Beta, it is still not given stable status by any means and is subject to change. I would like to understand when I could possibly enjoy the Beta features as an official next release.

Thank you,

+Alyssa+

Comment: Microsoft points to Stackoverflow for further discussion about the api. That's not my fault, please do not make me look like it is.

Comment: I don't say it's your fault, I just say that I don't think this is a suitable question for SO - which is not microsoft-support, whether they point here (the only thing I see is "for questions about your code") or not.

Comment: thank you for this useful response.

Answer (score 2):

Any new API that is implemented is first added to Graph Beta and then to v1.0. 
There is no one point in time where all beta api's will be moved to v1.0. Each API moves at its own cadence.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sivaprakash for this. The own cadence is what I was really after, but I guess only the Microsoft knows and won't tell us. It's btw. good to ask things in various places that get indexed by Google. Not only within Microsoft site itself, so that will also add some extra pressure for them to provide information and answers. Have a good day.

Comment: Furthermore - can I make a product for public release and distribution being based on Beta API? When they keep their right for any changes at will and at any time, how could I guarantee anything for the users of my product? Should I wait until Beta becomes the next official release and gets out of beta API endpoints aswell, or should I just go and push to market?

Comment: @AlyssaSkogs  You should wait until features move to the v1.0 endpoint before releasing production applications using those features.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Thank you very much for your answer. It all makes sense to me. Case closed.